# How can I compute the o/p of the code with memory model Diagram ? Why this is giving segmentation fault?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

```
int main()
{
    char a[2][3][3] = {'g','a','t','e','s','q','u','i','z','a','w'};
    printf("%s ", ***a);
    return 0;
}
```

This code gives Seg Fault on ***a. Kindly explain with Memory diagram how this array is stored in memory. Correct me if I am wrong 2 arrays of 3 row and 3 height. Also tell if the empty spaces store '/0' or garbage Value.

Comment: The identical question was deleted by asker, just after changing "%s " to "%c ". Is that relevant for you? Maybe the asker is a colleague of you working on the same assignment.

Comment: The short answer is that `***a` is a `char` and then `"%s"` is not the correct format. Your compiler should be able to tell you that: *error : format specifies type 'char \*' but the argument has type 'char'*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because   `printf("%s ", ***a);` converts the char `'g'` into a pointer which is invalid for the obvious reasons - as char conversion to the pointer is the UB

See the difference in this function (mind the zero at the end as well)

```
int zz()
{
    char a[2][3][3] = { 'g','a','t','e','s','q','u','i','z','a','w',0 };
    printf("%s ", &***a);
    return 0;
}
```

or

```
int yyy()
{
    char a[2][3][3] = { 'g','a','t','e','s','q','u','i','z','a','w',0 };
    char *ptr = **a;
    while (*ptr) printf("%c", *ptr++);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "is invalid for the obvious reasons" obviously the reasons are not obvious for the OP, hence the question.

Comment: "Because printf("%s ", ***a); converts the char 'g' into a pointer " when I write printf("%c ", ***a); the o/p is 'g' but not in the case of %s, can u put more light on this.

Comment: ***a dereferences the first element of the array (in this case 'g'). Then the integer value of the ASCII code 'g' is converted to the pointer - wchich points to the some illegal location in the memory. When you try to access this location you got the memory error

Answer (score 0):

If your goal was to demonstrate that a multidimensional array in C is just a single block of memory and in fact the `a` variable is just the address of its first byte then you could do it this way:

```
char a[2][3][3] = {'g','a','t','e','s','q','u','i','z','a','w'};

// Print all chars, this is ok because you've initialized your
// 12-element array by 11 chars and the last one is automatically set to 0
printf("%s\n", (char *)a);

// Print the first char
printf("%c\n", *(char *)a);
```